# Problem joining on the highest value in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a products table...

[alt text http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/6393/productscx5.gif](http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/6393/productscx5.gif)

and a revisions table, which is supposed to track changes to product info

[alt text http://img124.imageshack.us/img124/1139/revisionslz5.gif](http://img124.imageshack.us/img124/1139/revisionslz5.gif)

I try to query the database for all products, with their most recent revision...

```
select
*
from `products` as `p`
left join `revisions` as `r` on `r`.`product_id` = `p`.`product_id`
group by `p`.`product_id`
order by `r`.`modified` desc
```

but I always just get the first revision. I need to do this in **one** select (ie no sub queries). I can manage it in mssql, is this even possible in mysql?

Comment: What's wrong with subqueries? That's the way to do it. Or are you using an old version of mysql that doesn't support them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT p.*, r.*
FROM products AS p
  JOIN revisions AS r USING (product_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN revisions AS r2 
    ON (r.product_id = r2.product_id AND r.modified < r2.modified)
WHERE r2.revision_id IS NULL;
```

In other words: find the revision for which no other revision exists with the same product_id and a greater modified value.

Answer (score 1):

Begin and end dates on your history table would make this possible.(leaving the most recent end date null and stamping end dates on the previous record as you insert a new one)

Otherwise you will have to use a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

That same query is parsable in MySQL.

Why are you using a Left JOIN instead of an INNER join or a RIGHT join?

Also if you want to go about this in a different way, you have the MAX function at your disposal.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how the MAX function helps me in this situation?